# Use russian letter in section title

Tags: font-encodings

I try to typeset russian character by ascii letter, so I referenced [latex_cyrillic](http://www.gmarks.org/latex_cyrillic.pdf). It works but failed in section title. How to solve it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[OT2,OT1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\cyr{%
\renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
\renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
\renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
\normalfont
\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}
\def\Eob{\char3}
\def\eob{\char11}
\def\cpr{\char126}
\def\cdpr{\char127}
\def\Cpr{\char94}
\def\Cdpr{\char95}  

\begin{document}

\section{{\cyr L{ya}punov} theorem}
{\cyr Poslednee dokazatel\cpr stvo mozhno obobshchit\cpr
sleduyushchim zamechaniem, kotoroe nam eshche prigodit\mbox{}sya.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\protect` before `\cyr` in the section heading.

Comment: OK, `\protect\cyr` works. However, how to perfect the definition? @IanThompson

Comment: @MartinWang Keep in touch for an update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define `\cyr` as a robust command:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cyr{%
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
  \renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
  \renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
  \normalfont
  \selectfont}
```

By the way, your definitions such as

```
\def\Eob{\char3}
```

are wrong. Use either

```
\chardef\Eob=3
```

(more efficient) or

```
\newcommand\Eob{\symbol{3}}
```

They are not needed, anyway: you get the “e oborotnoye” by typing `e1` (lowercase)  or `E1` (uppercase). Similarly, the soft sign is `p1` or `P1` and the hard sign is `p2` or `P2`. The break between `t` and `s` is more conveniently obtained by `\/`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[OT2,OT1]{fontenc}

\DeclareRobustCommand\cyr{%
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
  \renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
  \renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
  \normalfont
  \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}

\newcommand\Eob{\symbol{3}} % or \chardef\Eob=3
\newcommand\eob{\symbol{11}}
\newcommand\cpr{\symbol{126}}
\newcommand\cdpr{\symbol{127}}
\newcommand\Cpr{\symbol{94}}
\newcommand\Cdpr{\symbol{95}}

\begin{document}

\section{{\cyr Lyapunov} theorem}
{\cyr Poslednee dokazatelp1stvo mozhno obobshchitp1sleduyushchim 
zamechaniem, kotoroe nam eshche prigodit\/sya.}

{\cyr \Eob\eob\Cpr\cpr\Cdpr\cdpr}

{\cyr E1e1P1p1P2p2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the problem? The boldface attribute is not honored because of `\normalfont`.

You can solve this by using

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cyr{%
  \fontfamily{wncy\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\f@family}{\sfdefault}=0 ss\else r\fi}%
  \fontencoding{OT2}%
  \selectfont}
\makeatother
```

[image]

---

An even more robust solution is to define the Washington University fonts as belonging to the `cmr` and `cmss` font family in the OT2 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[OT2,OT1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT2}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{it}{<->wncyi10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{sc}{<->wncysc10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{b}{n}{<->wncyb10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{bx}{n}{<->ssub*wncyr/b/n}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT2}{cmss}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmss}{m}{n}{<->wncyss10}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand\cyr{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}

\newcommand\Eob{\symbol{3}} % or \chardef\Eob=3
\newcommand\eob{\symbol{11}}
\newcommand\cpr{\symbol{126}}
\newcommand\cdpr{\symbol{127}}
\newcommand\Cpr{\symbol{94}}
\newcommand\Cdpr{\symbol{95}}

\begin{document}

\section{{\cyr Lyapunov} theorem}
{\cyr Poslednee dokazatelp1stvo mozhno obobshchitp1sleduyushchim 
zamechaniem, kotoroe nam eshche prigodit\/sya.}

{\cyr \Eob\eob\Cpr\cpr\Cdpr\cdpr}

{\cyr E1e1P1p1P2p2}

{\sffamily Abcdef\cyr Abcdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, all font attributes are honored (so long as the corresponding font in the OT2 encoding is available).

Comment: A simple question leads to a great answer. Thanks.